# Gegen ihren Willen oder Gegen ihrem Willen

Tags: grammatical-case

Sollte es nicht so heißen, wenn es um eine Frau geht?

> gegen **ihrem** Willen

Warum ist es ausgerechnet

> gegen **ihren** Willen?

Ist es dann nicht die Form von *sie* im Plural?

Answer (score 5):

Die Präposition *»gegen«* verlangt immer den Akkusativ. Daher muss das Possessivpronomen in genau diesem Fall stehen.

- männlich

  > **Der Mann** war dagegen. Die Tat geschah gegen **seinen** Willen.
- weiblich

  > **Die Frau** war dagegen. Die Tat geschah gegen **ihren** Willen.
- sächlich

  > **Das Kind** war dagegen. Die Tat geschah gegen **seinen** Willen.
- Plural

  > **Die Leute** waren dagegen. Die Tat geschah gegen **ihren** Willen.

---

Eine Präposition, die den Dativ verlangt, ist z.B. *»nach«*:

- männlich

  > **Der Mann** hat die Tat geplant. Sie geschah nach **seinem** Willen.
- weiblich

  > **Die Frau** hat die Tat geplant. Sie geschah nach **ihrem** Willen.
- sächlich

  > **Das Kind** hat die Tat geplant. Sie geschah nach **seinem** Willen.
- Plural

  > **Die Leute** haben die Tat geplant. Sie geschah nach **ihrem** Willen.

Answer (score 1):

Die vier Fälle von *ihr Wille* sind:

> - **Nominativ:**
>     
>   ihr Wille
>     → *„Es ist ihr Wille.“*
> - **Genitiv:**
>     
>   ihres Willens
>     → *„Es geschah ihres Willens wegen.“*
> - **Dativ:**
>     
>   ihrem Willen
>     → *„Wir fügen uns ihrem Willen.“*
> - **Akkusativ:**
>     
>   ihren Willen
>     → *„Sie unterschrieb gegen ihren Willen.“*

Im letzen Beispiel sieht man, dass die Präposition *gegen* den Akkusativ verlangt. Der Dativ, <s>*gegen ihre**m** Willen*</s>, wäre falsch.